# Update two ID's at once SQL - PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a table that's PK is an int field.
My problem is I need to swap two of the values round.

This is my current code:

```
$newId = (int)$id; $newId = $newId - 1;

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE homeScroller SET id = '$newId' WHERE id = '$id'") or die('error '.mysql_error()); 
$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE homeScroller SET id = '$id ' WHERE id = '$newId'") or die('error '.mysql_error());
```

The table contains at max 3 rows that contain info for an slideshow on the frontpage of the website. The frontpage orders them by their IDs. So to change the order I need to edit the ID's.

Comment: can you be more clear as to what you need to swap

Comment: Why do you need to swap them around? This is not a task that typically would happen in application code but would only be done at the database level.

Comment: you are making sure $id is an int too, right? ;)

Comment: Turns out i don't need an auto-increment so I've taken that out. I've also added the reason I need to change the id's.

Comment: Hmm - I'd prefer to add another column called Order and use it accordingly. PKs are used to identify unique records, so the idea of swapping and changing them to affect an order output makes me itch. Sorry :(

Comment: HOWEVER - if you don't have access to the call to change what it's ordering by, you may be safer to update all three rows with new ordering 0, 1, 2, otherwise you could potentially end up with some very low negative values after heavy use with current code. Multiple queries are not supported in the mysql_query command, so they'd have to be individual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The table contains at max 3 rows that contain info for an slideshow on the frontpage of the website. The frontpage orders them by their IDs. So to change the order I need to edit the ID's.

If that's the case, then your application/database is poorly architect-ed, and you need to re-think your database design before you go any further.

Primary keys should be immutable, i.e.: they should *never* change. What you're talking about doing is changing primary keys.

Fix your application/database, and you won't have this problem. Are you sure you shouldn't just be adding a new field 'sort_order' and ORDER BY sort_order instead or ordering by the ID field?

Comment: Indeed. Consider adding a `position` column to the `homeScroller` table and updating that instead.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 1):

Assign one with a temporary id (0, because auto_increment usually starts at 1, so 0 should be unused):

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE homeScroller SET id = 0 WHERE id = '$id'");
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE homeScroller SET id = '$id ' WHERE id = '$newId'");
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE homeScroller SET id = '$newId ' WHERE id = 0");
```

**IMPORTANT:** However, you shouldn't rely on the primary key for ordering results, if you want to be able to change the order easily. Add a `sequence` column and sort by that instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE  homeScroller
SET     id = CASE id WHEN $id THEN $newid ELSE $id END
WHERE   id IN ($id, $newid)
```

Comment: Fancy... :) Is this something supported by all/most SQL db engines?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use PK for this need.

If you can add timestamp field (shown_at) to this table, do it! 
if cant, so update all PKs imultaneously. Just increment them.
For example: suppose we have such strings:

```
  1 photo1
  3 myphoto
  5 somephoto

  than use modulo 3.
  1%3 = 1
  3%3 = 0
  5%3 = 2

  increment all records

  2 photo1
  4 myphoto
  5 somephoto

  2%3 = 2
  4%3 = 1
  6%3 = 0
```

So u can use modulo and increment ids